Why does json encode return an empty string?
I have a simple php structure with 3 nested arrays.
I do not use particular objects and I build myself the arrays with 2 nested loops.
Here is a sample of the var_dump of the array I want to convert to Json.
array (size=2)
  'tram B' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'Ile Verte' (length=9)
          'distance' => int 298
          'stationID' => int 762
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'La Tronche Hôpital' (length=18)
          'distance' => int 425
          'stationID' => int 771
  16 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'Bastille' (length=8)
          'distance' => int 531
          'stationID' => int 397
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'Xavier Jouvin' (length=13)
          'distance' => int 589
          'stationID' => int 438

In another script I have a similar structure and [tag:json_encode ]works fine. So I don't understand why [tag:json_encode] won't work here.
Edit : there seems to be a problem with the encoding. When mb_detect_encoding returns ASCII, the [tag:json_encode] works but when it returns UTF8, it doesn't work anymore.
Edit2 : json_last_error() returns JSON_ERROR_UTF8 which means : Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.

For our convenience, could you use var_export() instead of var_dump() to put the array in your question? Make sure you've tested the actual example you give in your question.

So if the php file/database input is not UTF8, then Hôpital will not be UTF8 - make sure the php/DB is not iso-8859-1 or windows-1252 or similar

Agreed, we need to see the raw data. A var_dump of it isn't  much use - we can't test that, or see what might exactly be the issue. var_export is ideal to give us a sample which causes the issue. See also how to make a [mre] of the problem

What does this have to do with javascript?

@Godot I agree, but the assumption, in this case, is that the array is written out in the PHP file, and not, for instance, coming from a database.

As the PHP collective we often refer to the answer on the question: UTF-8 all the way through. There are many tips there to get your UTF-8 flow correct. Will you give us an update on your problem?

You cound try json_encode($yourJsonArray, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);. This will ignore invalid characters and output something.

To answer the original question,  json_encode() cannot return an empty PHP string (at most, it can return a string with two double quotes only). I presume it's returning false, which is the signal for failure when you don't use the JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR flag.

@Leonard That is a particularly troublesome approach when dealing with French words.

@ÁlvaroGonzález The above approach can be only for troubleshooting and/or as a desperate safe final stage (before converting the strings).
